# bash script to alter array elements and write to new array

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I would like a bash script to take the elements from array1 and output them differently in array2.

array1 -

```
array1=(s3://root/sub1/sub2/ 2022-10-22 2021-09-13 2020-08-15 s3://root/sub1/sub2/ 2022-09-22 2021-08-07 2020-02-03  s3://root/sub1/sub2/ 2022-08-22 2021-07-17 s3://root/sub1/sub2/ 2022-07-22)
```

array2-

```
array2=(s3://root/sub1/sub2/2022-10-22/ s3://root/sub1/sub2/2021-09-13/ s3://root/sub1/sub2/2020-08-15/ s3://root/sub1/sub2/2022-09-22/ s3://root/sub1/sub2/2021-08-07/ s3://root/sub1/sub2/2020-02-03/ s3://root/sub1/sub2/2022-08-22/ s3://root/sub1/sub2/2021-07-17/ s3://root/sub1/sub2/2022-07-22/)
```

So I basically want to take the url from array1 and append each date that follows it and store as a unique entry in array2.

My thought process is as follows - loop through array1 for each url entry write to new array and append the dates to that url that follow it from array1. I am unsure how to do this in bash however.

Comment: Loop through the array. If the value begins with `s3:`, save it to a variable. If not, append the current value to the variable, and add that to the result array.

Comment: Not sure whether I understand your question: Do you have problems looping over an array, or do you don't know how to append a new element to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
array2=()
for elem in "${array1[@]}"; do
  if [[ $elem = s3:* ]]; then
    pfix=$elem
  else
    array2+=("$pfix$elem")
  fi
done
```